# Can I use jQuery to resize an iframe to fill the remaining window space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a div of height 90 pixels. Below it is an iframe.

I would like to figure out how to write javascript (or jQuery) to always set the iframe to the correct height to occupy the rest of the screen. If there is a better HTML5-based solution I would love to know about that too of course.

### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $window = $(window);
    function checkSize() 
    {
        var windowHeight = $window.height();
        var frameHeight = windowHeight - 90;
        $('iframe').height() = frameHeight; 
    }
    checkSize();
    $(window).resize(checkSize);

});
```

### HTML:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
<div style="height:90px;">
Content goes here
</div>

<iframe src="www.someurl.com" style="width:100%; height:900px; seamless: seamless; frameborder: 0;"></iframe>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Display your iframe as `block` first of all. You can then use the top of the iframe relative to the window height, to work out how far it is until the bottom:

**jQuery**

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    $window = $(window);
    $('iframe').height(function(){
        return $window.height()-$(this).offset().top;   
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
iframe{
    display:block; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    border:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/vud8S/4/)

Comment: Take a look at the JSFiddle, how does that differ to what you are doing?

Comment: The same principal applies. The fiddle is working, if you use the code correctly it should work jsfiddle or not.

Comment: I thought you would change the function in your actual code. I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/vud8S/1/) .. First and foremost, you didn't include jQuery (which is pretty important!). Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41649/discussion-between-ogeez-and-amy-neville)

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS may do the trick:

```
body, html { width:100% ;
    height:100% ;
    overflow:hidden ;
}

iframe { width:100% ; 
        height:100% ;
    border:none ;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgXcR/63/)

Comment: didn't make a difference unfortunately

Comment: ok this works ok but there is still 90 pixels larger than the window size. So you scroll down and the scroll bar continues down. It might be the best cross-browser solution though considering some have js disabled

Answer (score 0):

`$('iframe').height(frameHeight)`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gW9X4/)
Try this

Comment: might be a browser difference because not for me :)